# XSLT taking 2 XML files as input and generating output XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to generate an output XML file from a master xml file (Input1) based on data available in a decision xml file (Input2).

Master file

```
<Level1>

 <Level2>
  <LinkedTo>DATA1</LinkedTo> <!DATA1 in the decision file>
  <Attribute1>1</Attribute1>
  <Attribute2>2</Attribute2>
 </Level2>

 <Level2>
  <LinkedTo>DATA2</LinkedTo>
  <Attribute1>3</Attribute1>
  <Attribute2>4</Attribute2>
 </Level2>

</Level1>
```

Decision File:

```
<TopLevel>
 <DATA1>
  <Available>Y</Available>
 </DATA1>

 <DATA2>
  <Available>N</Available>
 </DATA2>

</TopLevel>
```

The XSLT when processed must output resultant file (Based on a YES or a NO in the decision file).

```
<Level1>
 <Level2>
  <Attribute1>1</Attribute1>
  <Attribute2>2</Attribute2>
 </Level2>
</Level1>
```

I must confess I have never done XML stuff before, but this is needed for a feasibility study. What should be in the XSLT? I can use your answers and extend the concept.

Or if there is an alternative (python,C#,C,C++ etc), those are welcome as well. I can manage with C/C++ or any procedure oriented language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function. Pass URI to decision XML, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Level1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Level2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Level2">
    <xsl:if test="document('Decision.xml')/TopLevel/*[
        name() = current()/LinkedTo and Available = 'Y']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::LinkedTo)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My apologies, I have been off stackoverflow for a while now. Both solutions(Kirill and Martin) worked equally well for me with a little tweak. I am also investigating other methodologies such as UML modeling for my problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here is an XSLT 2.0 solution that can be used with XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9, AltovaXML, XQSharp:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="dec-file" select="'decision.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="dec-doc" select="document($dec-file)"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="TopLevel/*" use="name()"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Level2[key('k1', LinkedTo, $dec-doc)/Available != 'Y']"/>

<xsl:template match="Level2[key('k1', LinkedTo, $dec-doc)/Available = 'Y']/LinkedTo"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```